# Partial text assertion and compare of 2 variables in selenium ide

Tags: testing, selenium-ide

I'm having a problem that I'm not sure how to solve. I have a customer code on one page (ex. Test095). I store it as var1.  And I have to navigate to another page and verify that the code is the same. But on the second page the customer code looks like this : Customer Code: Test095. I store is as var2. So I have to remove Customer Code words from here , so I can verify that var1 equals var2. How can I get rid of Customer Code words?

```
open |www.link.com
verify title | Page
assert text| css=tr:child(1)-example | Test095
store | css=tr:child(1)-example | var1
open |www.anotherlik.com 
assert text| xpath = //div[@id='myform']/div/div/p[4] | Customer code: Test095
store|xpath = //div[@id='myform']/div/div/p[4] |var2
verify| var2    | ${var1}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use java inbuit replace() function for string. Its better also to use trim incase to remove whitespaces

```
 String s = "Customer Code: Test095";
 s = s.replace("Customer Code:","").trim();
 System.out.println(s);
```

To make this work in Selenium IDE
use command 'execute script', as i used in screenshot below

[image]

Here 'y' will store value Test095

Comment: Is this for selenium ide? I only work with ide...could you explain me how I can use that for ide?

Comment: in order to use with selenium ide, you need to use command 'execute script' and replace with empty string. i will update my answer with screenshot of ide